# Bordered image with padding

Tags: css

I'm looking to give a pre-set style to all my medias like this 
http://prntscr.com/7b8w3g

Currently, I managed to give gray background by giving img tag a padding of 10px + background color as grey but when I give it border, it forms on the outter padding area whereas I want the thin border stick to picture like in above screenshot. That above picture is done via inline + div but I want to get it pre-set so all my pictures have it by default and all my pictures currently on my site have it. Any idea how to?
URL (http://www.freedomgolf.com.au/)

Thanks!!

Comment: To me, the dark border is on the inside, as is in the picture. I'm in chrome version 44 beta

Comment: Yup. same here. I'm on chrome. the thin black border should be sticked to picture whereas the lightgray bigger border should be outter layer.

Comment: To be clear, you want to get that wide-gray/thin-black border effect around the image using a CSS class without needing to wrap the image in a HTML element.

Comment: Yes. right now it's done via inline and a div but I want it kinda like pre-set for every future pics I add to + any other pics I have on the site. so for img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your specific problem, here's the idea to reproduce the thin dark border surrounded by a greater & lighter one:

```
img {
  background-color: #232323; // set the color of the dark thin border
  padding: 1px; // padding width make your thin dark border
  border: 10px solid #b2b2b2; // border make the grey area surrounding the thin border
}
```

[Run it without the comment](https://jsfiddle.net/on27squo/3/) :

```
img {
  background-color: #232323;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 10px solid #b2b2b2;
}
```

Hope I could help. :)

Comment: Cool! I updated the message with direct link to JS Fiddle, for other readers. :)

Comment: You guys rock! :) Keep up the good work. I got much to learn but will surely try to help around here.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with (CSS):

```
img{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #E5E4E2;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/on27squo/2/

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: I need that thin border too. The picture used in fiddler already have that border (like in the image itself)

Comment: Almost! I want that little black border which is close the image, too. The picture you used seem to have it without any css
can you try it via this image 
http://www.freedomgolf.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Experience.jpg

Comment: Yeah , saw that :) Thank you very much :)